# One-page HTML5 Web Application Should Not Have A Back Button?

Tags: html, web-applications

As I am working on an HTML5 web application working like a desktop app, I am wondering if the browser back button should be usable or not.

First, inside my app. As the design is close to a desktop application, I never change the url, so there is no history at all, it's a one page application.

Second, outside my app. I would tend to ask the user when she hits previous in history  if she wants to leave the application as the normal behavior is to go to a previous URL, which I think I should not prevent.

What do you think ? Is this approach reasonable?

Thanks!

---

After comments:

- When there is a back button on the broser page, this button should behave correctly. I agree.
- But if there is no back button, then it can make the web application look more like an application (and less like a web site). For example Google applications in chrome (e.g. mail, calendar) when opened in a dedicated window does not display any back button.

I will look more into the google solution to create a web app in a separated window running on chrome. I am wondering if it can be generalized.

---

Examples found:

https://www.draw.io/ - When going back, opens a dialog asking the user to choose to leave the app. I find that neat.

Comment: If the view changes then the user will expect the back button to take them back to the previous view. Breaking behavior that users expect is a good way to make them unhappy. Modern browsers have a [great API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) for this.

Comment: You mention you would ask the user when she hits previous. However, (speaking purely from personal experience) I have found that people usually don't read them and often find them annoying. Can you avoid them? Is it possible to bring the user back to their state if they accidentally hit back, and then hit forward to come back to your app?

Comment: @Jordan: You should make your response an answer so it can be up-voted / accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Per @NathanArthur's advice, posting this as an answer.)

If the view changes then the user will expect the back button to take them back to the previous view. Breaking behavior that users expect is a good way to make them unhappy. Modern browsers have a [great API for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Comment: If you expect a lot of users to be using your app outside the browser (like, as you mention, a Chrome app or e.g. Fluid), then you should consider those users' needs. Often native apps (especially on mobile where screen space is limited) have a "back" button in the UI--it's an intuitive metaphor for the user. Will the user want to "go back"? Just something to consider.

Comment: "If the view changes..." - that's exactly the part that is very, very hard to define.  What constitutes "the view changing"?  Changing a tab in a tab control?  Changing a filter for a table view?  Expanding/collapsing an accordion or tree node?  It gets even more complex if you have multiple of these things on screen and want to support the back button.   It gets even worse if the user assembles the view, say, in a component based system.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @DanielPaull. The best way to sort this kind of thing out is with asability testing.

Answer (score 7):

Why, not pushing States to the History? I would really recommend this to you, because you should try not to break normal behavior of users, they will always try to push that button, if they clicked something by accident. You could use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

Or is there a reason not to use the history ?